# Dual piecharts : total population vs. subpopulation

Tags: r, visualization, pie-chart

I'm trying to figure out some visualisation using piecharts to represent the frequencies of a total population vs. a subpopulation.

I'd like to represent either:

1. with angles defined by subpopulation frequencies (colors), and area (or radius size) of total population (gray) is adjusted:

[image: angles defined by subpopulation frequencies]

2. or with angles defined by the total population frequencies (gray), and area (or radius size) of total population (colors) is adjusted:

[image: angles defined by the total population frequencies]

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a R package that can do that for me ?
2. Which visualization is better, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REYec.png) or [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRdec.png) ?
3. Should I adjust radius size or area to compare total and subpopulations ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the `ggplot2` package with `coord_polar` and `geom_bar` the help topics of the functions should help you figure out how to create this plot.

Comment: Looking at your first plot - not the values- could you tell clearly that green is bigger than blue (and how much)? So it arises the 0 question: should I use pie charts? I'm not a pie-chart-ever-hater, but sometimes they could be misleading: not banning the knife, but to know when to use it.